# organize display of data from table

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

i have two tables rsales and salessumarry and i have this ff value.

value from salessumarry

```
date       |  receipt  |
09/29/2103 |  112233   |
```

values from rsales

```
name       |  category  | receipt  |
33uf       |  capacitor |  112233  |
ic         |  ic22      |  112233  |
```

THE EXPECTED OUTPUT MUST BE SOMETHING LIKE THIS.

```
    date       |  receipt  |
    09/29/2103 |  112233   |
   *name       | category  | receipt  |*
    33uf       | capacitor |  112233  |
    ic         | ic22      |  112233  |
```

but i get a result like this which is wrong. i have my code below so far.

```
    date       |  receipt  |
    09/29/2103 |  112233   |
   *name       | category  | receipt  |*
    33uf       | capacitor |  112233  |
   *name       | category  | receipt  |*
    ic         | ic22      |  112233  |
```

and i have this ff code so far

```
$a=$_POST['dayfrom'];
$b=$_POST['dayto'];

    $result1 = mysql_query ("SELECT s.*, r.category, r.name,r.receipt
    FROM salessumarry s
    JOIN rsales r ON s.reciept = r.reciept
    WHERE s.register_mode = 'sales'
    AND s.date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b' ");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td style="border-color:#000000; border-style:solid; border-width:1px;"><div align="center">'.$row['date'].'</div></td>';
        echo '<td style="border-color:#000000; border-style:solid; border-width:1px;"><div align="center">'.$row['reciept'].'</div></td>';
        echo '</div></td>';
        echo '</tr>';

        echo '<th style="border-color:#000000; border-style:solid; border-width:1px;"><div align="center">'.$row['name'].'</div>
        echo '<th style="border-color:#000000; border-style:solid; border-width:1px;"><div align="center">'.$row['category'].'</div></th>';
        echo '<th style="border-color:#000000; border-style:solid; border-width:1px;"><div align="center">'.$row['receipt'].'</div></th>';                              


        echo '<tr>';                        
        echo '<th style="border-color:#000000; border-style:solid; border-width:1px;font-size:10px;background-image:url(images/buts3.png);color:white"">name</th>';
        echo '<th style="border-color:#000000; border-style:solid; border-width:1px;font-size:10px;background-image:url(images/buts3.png);color:white"">category</th>';

        echo '<th style="border-color:#000000; border-style:solid; border-width:1px;font-size:10px;background-image:url(images/buts3.png);color:white"">receipt</th>';
 }
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Your "EXPECTED OUTPUT" looks terrible and ... illogical. How does that fit to your output table (headers)??

Comment: ok i edit it. try to watch it again

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry If I have misunderstood the question- the code you posted does not seem to produce the output you posted, nevertheless, here's my two cents; I think that to fix the problem you are having with the table headers repeating throughout the results, you need to place the block which reads:

```
 echo '<tr>';                        
    echo '<th style="border-color:#000000; border-style:solid; border-width:1px;font-size:10px;background-image:url(images/buts3.png);color:white"">Product Code</th>';
    echo '<th style="border-color:#000000; border-style:solid; border-width:1px;font-size:10px;background-image:url(images/buts3.png);color:white"">Name</th>';
```

In side an if block, such that it only displays once:

```
if(!$displayed) {
    $displayed = true;
    echo '<tr>';                        
    echo '<th style="border-color:#000000; border-style:solid; border-width:1px;font-size:10px;background-image:url(images/buts3.png);color:white"">Product Code</th>';
    echo '<th style="border-color:#000000; border-style:solid; border-width:1px;font-size:10px;background-image:url(images/buts3.png);color:white"">Name</th>';
}
```

And do not forget to initialize $displayed to false **before** the while loop.

In addition, but somewhat aside from the actual question this code you have posted is very insecure, as it is vulnerable to an attack known as sql injection. I recommend you use something like PDO prepared statements to make sure that you do not suffer security problems.